# DNS fails when 'Use this connection only for resources on its network' is checked

Tags: openvpn

It seems I can only have DNS or Routing working. Not both.

I imported my client's ovpn file and when I connect (with the defaults) I can access resources behind their firewall, their DNS servers take over, and all is good. Only problem: I can't access anything that's *not* on their server:

- `host onvpn.com` 123.45.67.89
- `host npr.org` 216.35.221.76
- `ping 123.45.67.89` SUCCEEDS
- `ping 216.35.221.76` FAILS

When I check off 'Use this connection only for resources on its network' I can still ping ips behind their server, but DNS on the server dies:

- `host onvpn.com` NOT FOUND
- `host npr.org` 216.35.221.76
- `ping 123.45.67.89` SUCCEEDS
- `ping 216.35.221.76` SUCCEEDS

If I uncheck `Automatic` for DNS (while still leaving "only resources on its network" checked off), and manually enter the addresses for the DNS servers I'm supposed to be using I get the same results.

Can I really only get Routing or DNS, pick one?

I'm on Zesty. I am using the `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` package to manage the connection. It works fine on my windows machine and Mac (with TunnelBlick) using default settings from the ovpn file.

== EDIT ==

I've run `systemd-resolve --status` in both states and it looks identical except a tilde in front of the domain when I have "Use this connection..." checked. I'm not sure how else to debug. I *really* don't want to use Windows or manually editing my hosts file...there's a lot of machines behind the VPN...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: @colin no dice. Just wrote a handful of scripts to use openvpn easily from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working as follows:

- Add another LAN connection profile, which has the IP address of the DNS server within the VPN
- Now if you use this profile, DNS is broken until you connect to VPN
- Therefore, change the VPN config to connect to a static IP address instead of a hostname (or put the IP address in your hosts file)

Done! It's not a workaround that makes me very happy, but hey, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just increased the route metric for the VPN, so a default gateway + DNS is added but the old default GW has higher priority. Then I added additional routes into the VPN network.

```
nmcli connection modify MYVPN ipv4.route-metric 101
```

Result: DNS servers from VPN, routing of VPN network (including DNS) through VPN, local network and internet via local gateway still available.